# Specifying prefix in opam file

Tags: ocaml, opam

I have an opam file with the line:

```
install: [make "install" "prefix=${prefix}$"]
```

my intent is that something like the following (which I have tested) will be executed by `opam install`:

```
make install prefix=/home/laheadle/.opam/4.02.0
```

In the Makefile I have:

```
install: js
    cp ./tournabox.css ./tournabox.js $(prefix)/lib
```

But I get the error:

```
#=== ERROR while installing tournabox.1.0 =====================================#
# opam-version 1.2.0
# os           linux
# command      make install prefix=${prefix}$
# path         /home/laheadle/.opam/4.02.0/build/tournabox.1.0
# compiler     4.02.0
# exit-code    2
# env-file     /home/laheadle/.opam/4.02.0/build/tournabox.1.0/tournabox-7593-d2c37b.env
# stdout-file  /home/laheadle/.opam/4.02.0/build/tournabox.1.0/tournabox-7593-d2c37b.out
# stderr-file  /home/laheadle/.opam/4.02.0/build/tournabox.1.0/tournabox-7593-d2c37b.err
### stdout ###
# ocamlbuild -cflag -annot -use-ocamlfind -pkgs js_of_ocaml.log,js_of_ocaml,js_of_ocaml.syntax -syntax camlp4o tournabox.byte
# js_of_ocaml +weak.js tournabox.byte
# lessc tournabox.less tournabox.css
# ocamlbuild -cflag -annot -use-ocamlfind -pkgs js_of_ocaml.log,js_of_ocaml,js_of_ocaml.syntax -syntax camlp4o tournabox.byte
### stderr ###
# make: *** Recursive variable `prefix' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPAM uses `%{prefix}%`, not `${prefix}$`.

You can see the use of prefix in [Creating OPAM Packages](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Packaging.html#CreatingOPAMpackages) part of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This error msg seems printed by make:

> ‘Recursive variable `xxx' references itself (eventually). Stop.’
>   This means you’ve defined a normal (recursive) make variable xxx that, when it’s expanded, will refer to itself (xxx). This is not allowed; either use simply-expanded variables (‘:=’ or ‘::=’) or use the append operator (‘+=’). See How to Use Variables.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html

Comment: But I don't understand how what I've written produces a recursive variable. Shouldn't opam expand the ${prefix}$ to something non-recursive?

Comment: If you expect opam to expand the variable `prefix`, you may take a look at https://github.com/ocaml/opam/wiki/Packaging#user-content-opam-variables .